# css with float left and close gaps - 2 cols

Tags: css, xhtml, stylesheet

I am building a drop down menu which will shows a second level. I am about 98% there, but i cant get it bang on. On the drop down menu for the second level, i want to show the results in two col's, with minimal space. At the moment, i have the two col's, but there is around 14px space to the left and also around 8 px space from the top.
Please help.
Many thanks:

I have updated the CSS, but still cant get it to close in on the drop second menus. Any ideas please

```
.drop_menu {
    LIST-STYLE-TYPE: none;
    HEIGHT: 38px; 

}

.drop_menu LI {
    float: left;
    background-color:#fff;
    height:40px;
    margin-top:-6px;
}

.drop_menu LI A {
    float: left;
    color: #000;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 1.389;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
 .drop_menu LI A:hover {
    COLOR: #fff; 
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #b52723;

}
.drop_menu UL {
    LIST-STYLE-TYPE: none; 
    POSITION: absolute; 
    LEFT: -999px; 
    Z-INDEX: 1000;
    TOP: -999px;
    margin-top:19px;
    margin-left:14px;
}
.drop_menu LI:hover {
    BACKGROUND: #fff;
    POSITION: relative;
}

.drop_menu LI:hover UL {
    BACKGROUND: #fff; 
    BORDER-TOP: #b52723 4px solid;
    BORDER-RIGHT: #ccc 1px solid;
    BORDER-BOTTOM: #ccc 1px solid; 
    BORDER-LEFT: #ccc 1px solid; 
    TOP: 30px; 
    WIDTH: 320px;
    LEFT: 0px; 
    padding:0;

}
.drop_menu LI:hover UL LI {

    MARGIN: 0px; 
    DISPLAY: block;

}
.drop_menu LI:hover UL LI A {
    width:140px;
    FONT-SIZE: 12px;
    padding:0;
    text-align: left;
    float:left;

    border:1px solid #333;

}
.drop_menu LI:hover UL LI A:hover {
    BACKGROUND: #fff; 
    COLOR: #b52723;

}
```

Thanks for the reply guys. Fiddle as requested

http://jsfiddle.net/dalew36/06pp180k/

Comment: can you add a fiddle ? so that we can see your html also

Comment: Change two properties on the following line to `.drop_menu LI:hover UL {left:0; top:30px}`

Comment: I don't see any top gap as you mention, but the gap on the left can be removed by adding `padding:0` to `.drop_menu LI:hover UL`. BTW, all your rules should be lowercase.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When i say gap, i want the sub menu links to "pad up" to reduce white space. The uppercase was done auto by using the style editor checker to see if there was any missing  elements